# Return to Main Window from User Control page

Tags: wpf

Can anyone share the code that would get me back to the main window without opening up a new window?

You can use this code to navigate between pages:

```
page1 page = new page1();
this.content = page;
```

However, you cannot use the code below to navigate back to the main window:

```
MainWindow home = new MainWindow();
this.content = home;
```

Any suggestions on how to get back to the main window without opening up a new one?

Comment: Yes they can. Can you ask a [proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specifying some actual details, or should we just guess your requirements?

Comment: Well to navigate from page to page you can use the code                   homePage home = new homePage();                                        this.content = home;                                                   but when I want to go back to the main window using the code               MainWindow main = new MainWindow();                                       this.content = main;                                                     it doesnt work....any sugestions?

Comment: I suggest that you *edit your question* and provide *all of the required information* there. To be clear, your comment does *not* provide all required information... just think of everything that you would need to know if someone asked *you* to do this.

Comment: It's a little bit better. Try reading through the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Make Page class have a reference to the Mainwindow through constructor

```
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {    
    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public Page1(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.startWindow = startWindow; 

        //SET Height and width to match the content of the page if it differs from 
        //mainwindow
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 450;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = 450;   
    }
```

Step 2 - In MainWindow when you want to change content to page1 create a method to change it

```
public void ChangeContentToPage1Action(){
    Page1 page = new Page1(this);
    this.content = page;
 }
```

Step 3 - Create an attribute in MainWindow that remembers the startup mainwindow content being shown. AND Create a method in MainWindow to get back to default content

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
    private object content;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        content = Content;
    }

 public void GoBackToStartPage()
        {
            Content = cont;
            //Sets the height and width of the application back to default if it differs from the page calling this method
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 200;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = 300;
        }
```

Step 4 - From Page1 class you can now call GoBackToStartPage() through mainWindow attribute and change the content back to default like this

```
mainWindow.GoBackToStartPage();
```

This helped me.

I hope somebody can use this